# Can SQL Server 2016 log files be applied on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016, transaction-log

This is in relation to a rollback scenario from a 2012 -> 2016 upgrade.

The scenario is that the SQL Server 2012 database is restored onto 2016 and log files applied until it is up to date. Then production systems are cut over to 2016.  Database is kept at compatibility level for 2012.  Subsequently, incremental logs from the 2016 instance are kept until the need to roll back (let's say 8 hours worth).

Can the logs now be applied to the SQL Server 2012 instance to bring that up to date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you bring the database online on SQL Server 2016, the database will be upgraded to the 2016 format, and will no longer be compatible with SQL Server 2012. **Those changes are fully logged operations, and will be contained in your transaction logs.**

The first transaction log backup taken on SQL Server 2016 will contain the script upgrade steps to bring the database from 2012 (110) to 2016 (130). If you attempt to apply that first transaction log backup to your copy of the database on SQL Server 2012, it will fail.

There is no way to do backup/restore (including log backups) to a lower version.

If you need to roll back, you would need to "manually" sync data--using either custom scripts, or a tool like Red Gate SQL Data Compare.

Generally, my preference is to not release the system for "public" use until after doing basic testing. If problems arise during smoke tests, you can roll back *without* having to sync data back to the lower version. If problems arise later, after smoke tests have passed, and after users are allowed back into the system--you commit to rolling forward and fixing the problem, rather than attempting to roll back.

Answer (score 2):

No we won't be able to do that. This is because the internal file structure is different.

You can use third party tools like SQL Compare and SQL Data Compare to do "diffing" between your source and target, generate update scripts from those differences, and then execute those scripts on the target platform; this works across different SQL Server versions.

I hope this helps

Comment: Are you sure the LOG format changes between 2012 and 2016 though? I understand backup/restore formats would.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.  SQL Server is like time travel: you can't go backwards.

Comment: Are you sure the LOG format changes between 2012 and 2016 though? I understand backup/restore formats would.

Comment: Log formats change too. They're essentially a binary format capturing the changes to be applied to blocks in the database. When new features are added in new version, the block format changes. And then the log format changes too.